# "npm faq" fails on Windows 7 ("spawn ENOENT" errors)

Tags: windows, node.js, npm

I have installed node.js on Windows 7 with their latest installer. It seemed to work, I can call `npm` and `node` from the console (either cmd or PowerShell), but I keep getting errors.

There are a lot of questions here about node.js on windows, but they all mention some specific piece of code. I'm getting the "spawn ENOENT" with a lot of simple commands, for instance `yo`, if I then pick "update generators" :

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:988:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:779:34)
```

even `npm faq` fails :

```
PS E:\www\something> npm faq
npm ERR! Error: spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!     at errnoException (child_process.js:988:11)
npm ERR!     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:779:34)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
```

It seems that the problem is that node uses unix command names like `dir`, which do not exist on Windows. Some blog posts mention using Cygwin, but mostly for *building* node.js, not for calling it. The official nodejs website doesn't mention that cygwin is a prerequisite, either.

Here's the npm-debug.log :

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'faq' ]
2 info using npm@1.3.24
3 info using node@v0.10.25
4 verbose node symlink C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe
5 error Error: spawn ENOENT
5 error     at errnoException (child_process.js:988:11)
5 error     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:779:34)
6 error If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
6 error including the npm and node versions, at:
6 error     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
7 error System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
8 error command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "faq"
9 error cwd E:\
10 error node -v v0.10.25
11 error npm -v 1.3.24
12 error syscall spawn
13 error code ENOENT
14 error errno ENOENT
15 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you have c:\Windows\System32 on your 'Path' System Variable. I was having this exact problem and this was the fix I needed. I must have taken it out in error sometime in the past.

Comment: I had the c:\Windows\System32 on my Path system variable, but it was second. When I made it first, everything worked! Thanks!